# Applying a class to the :first-child once only when creating a list dynamically with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok, so I'm loading a list of images by directory using PHP:

```
<?php
    # fetch image details
    $images = getImages("marc/img/livingrooms/");

    # display on page
    foreach($images as $img) {
        echo "<li><img src=\"{$img['file']}\" title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
    }
?>
```

Then I'm using the Galleria JQuery plugin to style those items into a gallery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.dynolist').addClass('gallery_group'); // adds new class name to maintain degradability

    $('ul.gallery_group').galleria({
        history   : true, // activates the history object for bookmarking, back-button etc.
        clickNext : true, // helper for making the image clickable
        insert    : '#main_image', // the containing selector for our main image
        onImage   : function(image,caption,thumb) { // let's add some image effects for demonstration purposes

            // fade in the image & caption
            image.css('display','none').fadeIn(1000);
            caption.css('display','none').fadeIn(1000);

            // fetch the thumbnail container
            var _li = thumb.parents('li');

            // fade out inactive thumbnail
            _li.siblings().children('img.selected').fadeTo(500,0.3);

            // fade in active thumbnail
            thumb.fadeTo('fast',1).addClass('selected');

            // add a title for the clickable image
            image.attr('title','Next image >>');
        },
        onThumb : function(thumb) { // thumbnail effects goes here

            // fetch the thumbnail container
            var _li = thumb.parents('li');

            // if thumbnail is active, fade all the way.
            var _fadeTo = _li.is('.active') ? '1' : '0.3';

            // fade in the thumbnail when finnished loading
            thumb.css({display:'none',opacity:_fadeTo}).fadeIn(1500);

            // hover effects
            thumb.hover(
                function() { thumb.fadeTo('fast',1); },
                function() { _li.not('.active').children('img').fadeTo('fast',0.3); } // don't fade out if the parent is active
            )
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is that I need to give the first item pulled from that list a class of "active", so the first image will be loaded into the slideshow. Everything else works right now, other than getting that first image loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# display on page
$counter = 0;
foreach($images as $img) {

  if ($counter == 0) { // first
    echo "<li class=\"active\"><img src=\"{$img['file']}\" title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<li><img src=\"{$img['file']}\" title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
  }

  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: @Anders H: That is great news :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('selector:first').addClass('active');
```

Maybe?

Or what about

```
# display on page
$class = 'class="active" ';
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<li><img ".$class."src=\"{$img['file']}\" title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
    $class="";
}
```

Comment: Didn't see the edit before testing, this may work but I just took the PHP solution above.

Comment: @Anders H: This is a PHP solution as well, and a more elegant one at that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that on the PHP side, you could count, in your foreach loop, how many images have been displayed -- and if 0 have been displayed, add a `class="active"` to the one you are currently echoing.

For instance, something like this should do the trick :

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<li><img src=\"{$img['file']}\" ";
    if ($counter === 0) {
        echo 'class="active"';
    }
    echo " title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
    $counter++;
}
```

The first time you'll loop, `$counter` will be `0`, and `class="active"` will be echoed ; next times, it won't be 0 anymore, and no addtionnal `active` class will be added.

Answer (score 1):

In jquery:

```
$(".gallery_group li:first-child").addClass("active");
```

In php:

```
# display on page
$first = true;
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<li " . ($first ? "class='active'" : "") . "><img src=\"{$img['file']}\" title=\"\" alt=\"\"></li>\n";
    $first = false;
}
```